# Angular 2 RC.6 form input patten never passes

Tags: forms, validation, angular

I am trying to make it so that the required input in my form doesn't pass validation unless there's at lease one non-whitespace character in the value, however for some reason the validation never passes. Am I missing an import or something?

Template:

```
<form #createForm='ngForm'>
    <input type='text' required pattern='[/S]+' name='projectName' [(ngModel)]='projectName' placeholder='Give your project a name...' class='focusOnMe'>
</form>
```

Component:

```
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';

Component({
  selector: 'cmg-modal-create',
  template: require('./modals.create.html')
})

export class ModalCreateComponent extends CreateModal {
    ...
}
```

Module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ModalCreateComponent
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ...
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the regex just didn't work like I expected. I ended up with this pattern which says that the first character can't be a whitespace. I'd like to update it do that the first character can be a whitespace as long as there is another character after it, but I've been unable to figure that out.

```
<input type='text' name='projectName' [(ngModel)]='projectName' required pattern='[^\s][\W\w]+' placeholder='Give your project a name...' class='focusOnMe'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code sample with custom validation:
https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/blob/master/chapter7/form-samples/app/06_custom-validator-directive.ts

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. The question should contain the most relevant parts directly.